# Populating complex objects from view, on post, using interfaces

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to post data from a bunch of text fields using the following:

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Order()
        {
            OrderViewModel vm = new OrderViewModel();
            vm.Id = "some id";
            List<IOrderItem> itemList= new List<IOrderItem>();
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                OrderItem x = new OrderItem();
                x.ItemId = i + "";
                itemList.Add(x);
            }
            vm.OrderItemList = itemList;
            return View(vm);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Order(OrderViewModel model)
        {
            return View("blabla");
        }
```

These are the models:

```
public class OrderViewModel : B.IOrderItemViewModel
{

    private List<IOrderItem> orderItems;
    public List<IOrderItem> OrderItemList
    {
        get { return orderItems; }
        set { orderItems = value; }
    }

    private string orderId;
    public string Id
    {
        get { return orderId; }
        set { orderId = value; }
    }


}

public class OrderItem : IOrderItem
{
    private string orderItemId;
    public string ItemId
    {
        get { return orderItemId; }
        set { orderItemId = value; }
    }

    private string _description;
    public string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set { _description = value; }
    }
}
```

this is the view:

```
@model OrderViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Order", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.OrderItemList.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.OrderItemList[i].ItemId)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.OrderItemList[i].Description)
        <br />
    }

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

Here is the problem - The interfaces are in another project, let's call it B. I reference B in the project.json file for the main project, A. In B, I just defined the two interfaces the are inherited above.

If I do not use any interfaces, and I just use the objects 
e.g. instead of :

```
List<IOrderItem> OrderItemList
```

I use :

```
List<OrderItem> OrderItemList
```

When I run the project, and hit the view, I see the textboxes. I fill in some data and hit submit. It goes to the controller as expected. If I put a breakpoint in the HttpPost actionresult method, and look at the model, I can see all the data I entered. Perfect.

If I use the code above, where I am inheriting from some interfaces, it does not work. The view loads, I enter in some data, I post, it hits the breakpoint, but the model is empty and it's all null.

Any ideas / help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Side note, you can use the Razor `@foreach` syntax. You don't need an index variable and it will automatically iterate over the list and you won't have to access via the index again (`orderItem.ItemId` instead of `x.OrderItemList[i].ItemId`)

Comment: I don't think that will work. If I use a foreach, the ID and name value would be the exact same for every input. The point of using the for, is so that every name is unique.

Comment: I suggest you try my suggestion before dismissing it. It'll lead to a cleaner syntax, which makes your site easier to update and debug.

Comment: I am not dismissing it. I have tried it. It can't work because id's need to be unique. There are many articles on the web that explain that further. I do agree it's cleaner but that is not the issue I'm having. The code works without interfaces, it does not with interfaces. I'm just trying to understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant bind to interfaces. The process of model binding involves first initializing your model (internally the `DefaultModelBinder` uses `Activator.CreateInstance()`) , but you can't initialize an interface (how would it know which type to initialize), which is why

```
public List<OrderItem> OrderItemList { get; set; }
```

works, but

```
public List<IOrderItem> OrderItemList { get; set; }
```

wont.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) discusses it more detail and includes a section on creating a custom Abstract Model Binder that may solve your problem.